# Fortran mimic R and Python fixing random number seeds

Tags: python, r, fortran

Numerical experiments for repeatability can be done by set random seeds in R and Python, with toy examples respetively as follows:

**R**

```r
set.seed(100)
x1 = runif(3)
print(x1)
# [1] 0.3077661 0.2576725 0.5523224


set.seed(100)
x2 = runif(3)
print(x2)
# [1] 0.3077661 0.2576725 0.5523224


set.seed(200)
x3 = runif(3)
print(x3)
# [1] 0.5337724 0.5837650 0.5895783
```

**Python**

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
x1 = np.random.rand(3)
print(x1)
# [0.54340494 0.27836939 0.42451759]

np.random.seed(100)
x2 = np.random.rand(3)
print(x2)
# [0.54340494 0.27836939 0.42451759]

np.random.seed(200)
x3 = np.random.rand(3)
print(x3)
# [0.94763226 0.22654742 0.59442014]
```

I tried setting random seeds in Fortran mimic R and Python as follows:

```
program set_seed_test

implicit none
integer :: s1, s2, s3
real :: x1(3) = 0.0, x2(3) = 0.0, x3(3) = 0.0
integer :: i

s1 = 100
call random_seed(size = s1)
call random_number( x1 ) 
write(*,*) x1

s2 = 100
call random_seed(size = s2)
call random_number( x2 ) 
write(*,*) x2

s3 = 200
call random_seed(size = s3)
call random_number( x3 ) 
write(*,*) x3

end program set_seed_test
```

which shows different results as

```
 0.997559547      0.566824675      0.965915322
  0.747927666      0.367390871      0.480636895
   7.37542510E-02   5.35517931E-03  0.347081244
```

Why this happens?  Also , can we write a module `set_seed` for Fortran fixing random seeds?

Comment: *can we write a module set_seed?* Well I'm sure you could, but before you do you might want to investigate the `put` argument for `random_seed` which is provided so that you can set the seed to a specific value.  You're also misunderstanding the `size` argument, your documentation will clarify.

Comment: For repeatability across compilers and (often) better quality, don't use the built-in random number generator, as implementations vary greatly.